# Particular solution of this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $(D^2+4D+4)y =x^2 +2x$

I have trouble in particular solution.

My particular solution is :

$y_p$=$Ax^2+Bx+C$

Solving for this I get A=1/4 ,B=0 and C=-1/8 and $y_p=x^2/4-1/8$ but the solution is given to be $\frac {2x^2+3}{8}$.Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: It is probably a typo in the textbook. The proposed particular solution would be good if the RHS was $x^2+2x+2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing  wrong with your answer. The given answer is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the particular solution given is for $(D^{2}+4D+4)y=x^{2}+2x+2$. Did you copy the DE wrongly?

Comment: No. It's same as in my textbook